# Serialization error in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, sorm

What should we do if Akka serialisation fails because it couldn't find one of the mixed in trait?

The message is constructed using case class`TestResult(config: TestConfiguration)`. However, since `TestConfiguration` is fetched from a database using SORM, the actual type is `TestConfiguration with Persisted`, hence the error.

I tried mixing out using `mixoutPersisted` but it doesn't work.
Maybe it's because `TestConfiguration` contains another `Entity` in its field, but I'm not sure whether `mixoutPersisted` already handle this.

Full stack trace here

```
[ERROR] [07/20/2015 12:19:25.834] [hipci-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] [akka.tcp://hipci@127.0.0.1:57052/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Fhipci%40127.0.0.1%3A2552-0/endpointWriter] AssociationError [akka.tcp://hipci@127.0.0.1:57052] -> [akka.tcp://hipci@127.0.0.1:2552]: Error [__wrapper$1$a8720f07eaff412d8409f3359d68f6d1.__wrapper$1$a8720f07eaff412d8409f3359d68f6d1$PersistedAnonymous1$1] [
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: __wrapper$1$a8720f07eaff412d8409f3359d68f6d1.__wrapper$1$a8720f07eaff412d8409f3359d68f6d1$PersistedAnonymous1$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:625)
    at akka.util.ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.scala:19)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$1.apply(Serializer.scala:136)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.fromBinary(Serializer.scala:136)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:104)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:98)
    at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:23)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$lzycompute$1(Endpoint.scala:58)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$1(Endpoint.scala:58)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:76)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:929)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:405)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
]
```

Using Akka 2.3.12 and SORM 0.3.18

Comment: The name of class `__wrapper$1$a8720f07eaff412d8409f3359d68f6d1.__wrapper$1$a8720f07eaff412d8409f3359d68f6d1$PersistedAnonymous1` looks like the class is generated with something like `scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox` (`toolbox.define(..)`/ `toolbox.eval(..)`). It is important that toolbox-generated classes live in the toolbox mirror (class loader) different from the original runtime mirror (class loader) that the toolbox was created with.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the JARs in both machines aren't the same. Java Serialization sends only the object's attributes, not the code, so if a class is not found on one side it usually means that the contents of the CLASSPATH on the receiving end don't match those on the sending end.